# How to know if a key is Primary or Foreign?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am learning the basics of SQL but I am running into some problems with keys.

Lets say we have two tables:

**Student** (PK = ID)

Columns: `ID / Name / Age`

**StudentResult** (PK = ID + Date)

Columns: `ID / Date / Grade / Result`

My textbook tells me that `ID` cannot be the primary key in the `StudentResult` table as:

*A foreign key must contain all the columns of the primary key of the other table.*

I am having a hard time understanding this.

1. Does this mean in order for `StudentResult` to have `ID` as a primary key, it must also have the `Name` and `Age` columns?
2. Why can't `ID` be the foreign key in the `Student` table given the above statement?

I hope someone can help as I really want to get a better understanding of how this works so I can move on.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but read the bold bit again. What is the **primary key** of the other table? It doesn't say "must contain all of the fields (sic) of the table that contains the primary key", it says "must contain all of the fields of the primary key"

Comment: Ok I think I understand. 
Student Table does not contain all the fields of the primary key of the StudentResult table (ID, Date).
Whereas the StudentResult table does contain all the fields of the primary key of the Student table (ID) - Therefore ID in the StudentResult table must be the foreign key?
Am I getting this right?

Comment: If you want to establish a foreign key relationship between `StudentResult` and `Student`, the foreign key in `StudentResult` must contain **all columns that make up the PK of `Student`**, e.g. your foreign key must be a `StudentID` that references the PK of `Student` - the `ID`. The FK must reference all columns **OF THE PK** - not the whole table!

Answer (score 1):

In order for tables to adhere to "relational theory", each table (aka instantiated relation) must have a "candidate key", which is a column that does not contain duplicate values.

These candidate keys are suited to serve as a table's Primary Key.

In your case, the `[Student]` table should have its PK be `[ID]`, and the `[Student Result]` table should have its PK be `[ID]`. In addition, you can declare a foreign key on `[Student Result].[ID]` that refers to `[Student].[ID]`. What this means is: you cannot have a row in `[Student Result]` whose `ID` does not exist in `[Student].[ID]`. If you think about it, this makes sense: how can you have a student's grade posted if the student in question does not exist?

Comment: Hi, I completely understand the point of the PK and FK but it was the bolded part in my original question at the top of the page that confused me. I have some questions in my assignment asking why a key in one table can't be a primary key and it has something to do with the bolded text in my OP.

Comment: Ok, I see now. In your case, you would need a `[DATE]` field in your `[Student]` table, and it would need to be part of your PK in that table. All of the columns (aka instantiated attributes) that comprise a FK in one table need to be included in a candidate key in the table the FK is pointing to.

Comment: Thanks I think I got it. How do I give you guys reputation?

Comment: Cool. You can hit the grey up/down arrows, and if you decide an answer satisfies your question, you can click on the checkmark.